# *RPG-Engine Troubleshoot (AS3): "Multiple Levels" code snippet returns a "null" HitTestObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe, flash-cs4

***Hello!**
    I'm working on an open-source game engine scripted in AS3
and I am attempting to have the MC advance to another area/level...

***How it Works/The Idea...**
    When the MC obtains a key, it is used to turn kameHouseLocked to kameHouseOpen. 
When the kameHouse is set to open the player can hold the "up arrow" towards the
 door to advance. I have two ways to achieve this, either within a movieclip or by 
calling whatever second layers are needed layers to the stage. The way my code is 
currently set up, it is unable to reference the kameHouse which is needed to trigger 
the event. The logic worked well enough for the key, should I make sure whatever is 
being referenced in encased within a movieclip? Do I need an independent snippet 
entirely to handle the collisions? Any help would really be appreciated, 
I will kindly credit you for any effort/involvement, thank you in advance!

***Output spits this out?**

```html
    TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
     at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
     at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
     at pokemongameexperiment/keyDownHandler()
```

***The Code in Question...**

```html
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


mc.gotoAndStop("standingRight");
toggle_btn.stop();
hide_text.stop();
stop();
//backenvironment.kamiHouse.stop();


var keyCodeToListenForDown = '40'; //downarrow key
var keyCodeToListenForUp = '38'; //uparrow key
var keyCodeToListenForLeft = '37'; //leftarrow key
var keyCodeToListenForRight = '39'; //rightarrow key

var keySinglePress:Boolean = false;
var keyDoublePress:Boolean = false;
var timeToWaitForDoublePress:Number = 300;
var waitingForDoublePress:Boolean = false;

var leftBumping:Boolean = false;
var rightBumping:Boolean = false;
var upBumping:Boolean = false;
var downBumping:Boolean = false;
var leftBumpPoint:Point = new Point(-30, -55);
var rightBumpPoint:Point = new Point(30, -55);
var upBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, -120);
var downBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, 0);

var pp:Boolean=true;
var played:Boolean=false;
var mySound:Sound = new MySound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

var rightPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var leftPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var upPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var downPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var mcSpeed:Number = 10;

var roshiTimer:int = 0;
var roshiDuration:int = 0;
var roshiFacing:int = 0;
var roshiSpeed:Number = 3
var RF:Array = 
["roshiUpWalk", "roshiDownWalk",
 "roshiLeftWalk", "roshiRightWalk",];
var RX:Array = [0, 0, -1, 1];
var RY:Array = [-1, 1, 0, 0];

var kameKeyCollected:Boolean = false;
var kameHouseOpen:Boolean = false;

var currentLevel:int = 1;


//kameHouse(2).prevBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, prevSection);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onRoshi);
toggle_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, togglePlay);

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown);
//kameHouse(2).nextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextSection);



//function prevSection(event:MouseEvent):void
//{
 //var thisLabel:String = pages.currentLabel;
 //var thisLabelNum:String = thisLabel.replace("sct", "");
 //var curNumber:Number = Number(thisLabelNum);
 //var prevNum:Number = curNumber - 1;
 //pages.gotoAndStop("sct" + prevNum);
//}

function handleKeyDown(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent) 
{ 
 if (keyEvent.keyCode == keyCodeToListenForDown)
 {
  keySinglePress = true;
  if (waitingForDoublePress){
   keyDoublePress = true;}
  
  waitingForDoublePress = true;
  
  setTimeout(function() {
      waitingForDoublePress = false;
   keyDoublePress = false;
   }, timeToWaitForDoublePress);
 }
 if (keyDoublePress){
  trace('You logged a double press!')}
  else if (keySinglePress) {
  trace ('You logged a single press!');
 }

 if (keyEvent.keyCode == keyCodeToListenForUp)
 {
  keySinglePress = true;
  if (waitingForDoublePress){
   keyDoublePress = true;}
  
  waitingForDoublePress = true;
  
  setTimeout(function() {
      waitingForDoublePress = false;
   keyDoublePress = false;
   }, timeToWaitForDoublePress);
 }
 if (keyDoublePress){
  trace('You logged a double press!')}
  else if (keySinglePress) {
  trace ('You logged a single press!');
 }
     if (keyEvent.keyCode == keyCodeToListenForLeft)
 {
      keySinglePress = true;
     if (waitingForDoublePress){
   keyDoublePress = true;}
  
  waitingForDoublePress = true;
  
  setTimeout(function() {
      waitingForDoublePress = false;
   keyDoublePress = false;
   }, timeToWaitForDoublePress);
 }
 if (keyDoublePress){
  trace('You logged a double press!')}
  else if (keySinglePress) {
  trace ('You logged a single press!');
 }
  if (keyEvent.keyCode == keyCodeToListenForRight)
 {
  keySinglePress = true;
  if (waitingForDoublePress){
   keyDoublePress = true;}
  
  waitingForDoublePress = true;
  
  setTimeout(function() {
      waitingForDoublePress = false;
   keyDoublePress = false;
   }, timeToWaitForDoublePress);
 }
 if (keyDoublePress){
  trace('You logged a double press!')}
  else if (keySinglePress) {
  trace ('You logged a single press!');
 }
}

 
//hide_text.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopMovie);
function ppState(event:MouseEvent){
if(pp){
stop();
hide_text.gotoAndStop(3);
//hide_text.gotoAndStop('stopText');
pp = false;
}else{
//hide_text.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMovie);
 play(); 
 hide_text.gotoAndStop(1);
 //hide_text.gotoAndStop('playText');
 pp = true;
}
}
hide_text.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ppState);
                 
function togglePlay(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   (!played)? played = true : played = false;
   (played)? myChannel=mySound.play():SoundMixer.stopAll();

   (played)? toggle_btn.gotoAndStop(2):toggle_btn.gotoAndStop(1);
    myChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,soundCompleted);
}
function soundCompleted(event:Event):void
{
 played = false;
 toggle_btn.gotoAndStop(1);
}





function nextLevel():void
{
 currentLevel++;
 trace("Next Level: " + currentLevel);
 if(currentLevel == 2)
 {
  gotoLevel2();
 }
}
function gotoLevel2():void
{
 //gotoAndStop(2);
 //frontenvironment2.gotoAndStop;
 backenvironment.gotoAndStop(2);
 frontenvironment.gotoAndStop(2);
 gotoAndStop(frontenvironment2);
 //scrollx = 0;
 //scrolly = 0;
 //backenvironment.gotoAndStop
 //backenvironment.gotoAndStop
}

function gameLoop(loopEvent:Event):void 
{         
    if(rightPressed && mc.currentLabel !="walkingRight" && upPressed == false && downPressed == false)
 { 
       mc.gotoAndStop("walkingRight");
    }
    if(rightPressed && mc.currentLabel =="walkingRight")
    {
    if(mc.x < 800)
    {
          mc.x += mcSpeed;
    }

    else if (backenvironment.x > -650) 
    {
    backenvironment.x -= mcSpeed; 
    frontenvironment.x -= mcSpeed;
    }
    } 
  if(keyDoublePress && mc.currentLabel =="walkingRight")
    {
    if(mc.x < 800)
    {
          mc.x += mcSpeed * 1.05;
    }

    else if (backenvironment.x > -650) 
    {
    backenvironment.x -= mcSpeed; 
    frontenvironment.x -= mcSpeed;
    }

    }
 
    if(leftPressed && mc.currentLabel !="walkingLeft" && upPressed == false && downPressed == false)
    {
       mc.gotoAndStop("walkingLeft");
    }
    if(leftPressed && mc.currentLabel =="walkingLeft")
    {
    if(mc.x > 200)
    {
          mc.x -= mcSpeed;
    }
    else if (backenvironment.x < -130)
    {
       backenvironment.x += mcSpeed;
       frontenvironment.x += mcSpeed;
    }
 }
 if(keyDoublePress && mc.currentLabel =="walkingLeft")
    {
    if(mc.x > 200) 
    {
          mc.x -= mcSpeed * 1.05;
       }
    else if (backenvironment.x < -130) 
    {
       backenvironment.x += mcSpeed;
       frontenvironment.x += mcSpeed;
    }
    }
 
    if(upPressed && mc.currentLabel != "walkingUp" && rightPressed == false && leftPressed == false)  
 {
       mc.gotoAndStop("walkingUp");
    }
    if(upPressed && mc.currentLabel == "walkingUp")
    {
    if(mc.y > 200) 
    {
          mc.y -= mcSpeed;10
       }
    else if (backenvironment.y < -10) 
    {
       backenvironment.y += mcSpeed;
       frontenvironment.y += mcSpeed;
    }
 }
 
    if(keyDoublePress && mc.currentLabel =="walkingUp")
       {
    if(mc.y > 200) 
    {
          mc.y -= mcSpeed * 1.05;10
       }
    else if (backenvironment.y < -10) 
    {
       backenvironment.y += mcSpeed;
       frontenvironment.y += mcSpeed;
    }
  
 }
    
    if(downPressed && mc.currentLabel != "walkingDown" && rightPressed == false && leftPressed == false)
    {
       mc.gotoAndStop("walkingDown");
    }
 
    if (downPressed && mc.currentLabel == "walkingDown")
    {
    if(mc.y < 485) 
    {
          mc.y += mcSpeed;
       }
    else if (backenvironment.y > -577) 
       {
     backenvironment.y -= mcSpeed;
     frontenvironment.y -= mcSpeed;
       }
    }
    if (keyDoublePress && mc.currentLabel == "walkingDown")
    {
   if(mc.y < 485)
   {
    mc.y += (mcSpeed * 1.05);
   }
   else if (backenvironment.y > -577)
   {
    backenvironment.y -= mcSpeed;
    frontenvironment.y -= mcSpeed;
   } 
 }
//add more walking functionality here if needed (ex: multi-directional).
}   


//Roshi's_Brain:
function onRoshi(e:Event):void
{
   if(mc.hitTestObject(backenvironment.Roshi))
   {
      myText.text = "Master Roshi: R- Red? Oh dear... this is bad. I've barely introduced myself. I'm Master Roshi, headmaster of the Turtle School of Martial Arts!"; 
   }
   else
   {
   myText.text = "Master Roshi: Red... You have to find Goku. My back, it's delicate!"; 

      roshiTimer ++; 

      if (roshiTimer > roshiDuration)
      {
         roshiDuration = 10 + Math.random() * 25;
         roshiTimer = 0;
  
         while (backenvironment.Roshi.currentLabel == RF[roshiFacing])
         {
            roshiFacing = Math.random() * 4;
         }

      backenvironment.Roshi.gotoAndStop(RF[roshiFacing]);
   }

    backenvironment.Roshi.x += RX[roshiFacing] * roshiSpeed;
    backenvironment.Roshi.y += RY[roshiFacing] * roshiSpeed;
}
if(kameKeyCollected == false)
{ // if we still haven't collected the key
 if(mc.hitTestObject(backenvironment.kameKey))
 { // and if the player collides with the key
  backenvironment.kameKey.visible = false; // hide the key from view
  kameKeyCollected = true; // set our Boolean to true
 }
 
}

if(kameHouseOpen == false)
{ // if the door hasn't been opened yet
 if(kameKeyCollected == true)
 { // and if the player has already collected the key
     if(mc.hitTestObject(backenvironment.kameHouse))
  { // check if the door and the player are touching
        // if all of these conditions are met...
        backenvironment.kameHouse.gotoAndStop(2); // ...switch the door's image to its 2nd frame
        kameHouseOpen = true; // ...set the variable to true
        }
    }
}

}
function keyDownHandler(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
   if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
   {
    rightPressed = true;
   }
   else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
   {
    leftPressed = true;
   }
   else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
   {
    downPressed = true;
   }
   else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
   {
    upPressed = true;
    if(kameHouseOpen && mc.hitTestObject(backenvironment.kameHouse.kameHouseLocked))
    { 
       nextLevel(); 
    }
   }
}

function keyUpHandler(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
   if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
   {
    rightPressed = false;
    mc.gotoAndStop("standingRight");
   }
   else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
   {
 leftPressed = false;
 mc.gotoAndStop("standingLeft");
   }
   else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
   {
       downPressed = false;
    mc.gotoAndStop("standingDown");
   }
   else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
   {
    upPressed = false;
    mc.gotoAndStop("standingUp");
   }
}
```

**Revised Code**

```html
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///Dev Notes: Poke Ball Z (Ver. 0.3.8)//////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


mc.gotoAndStop("standingRight");
toggle_btn.stop();
hide_text.stop();
stop();
//backenvironment.kamiHouse.stop();


var keyCodeToListenForDown = '40'; //downarrow key
var keyCodeToListenForUp = '38'; //uparrow key
var keyCodeToListenForLeft = '37'; //leftarrow key
var keyCodeToListenForRight = '39'; //rightarrow key

var keySinglePress:Boolean = false;
var keyDoublePress:Boolean = false;
var timeToWaitForDoublePress:Number = 300;
var waitingForDoublePress:Boolean = false;

var leftBumping:Boolean = false;
var rightBumping:Boolean = false;
var upBumping:Boolean = false;
var downBumping:Boolean = false;
var leftBumpPoint:Point = new Point(-30, -55);
var rightBumpPoint:Point = new Point(30, -55);
var upBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, -120);
var downBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, 0);

var pp:Boolean=true;
var played:Boolean=false;
var mySound:Sound = new MySound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

var rightPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var leftPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var upPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var downPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var mcSpeed:Number = 10;

var roshiTimer:int = 0;
var roshiDuration:int = 0;
var roshiFacing:int = 0;
var roshiSpeed:Number = 3
var RF:Array = 
["roshiUpWalk", "roshiDownWalk",
 "roshiLeftWalk", "roshiRightWalk",];
var RX:Array = [0, 0, -1, 1];
var RY:Array = [-1, 1, 0, 0];

var kameKeyCollected:Boolean = false;
var kameHouseOpen:Boolean = false;

var currentLevel:int = 1;


//kameHouse(2).prevBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, prevSection);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onRoshi);
toggle_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, togglePlay);

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown);
//kameHouse(2).nextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextSection);



//function prevSection(event:MouseEvent):void
//{
 //var thisLabel:String = pages.currentLabel;
 //var thisLabelNum:String = thisLabel.replace("sct", "");
 //var curNumber:Number = Number(thisLabelNum);
 //var prevNum:Number = curNumber - 1;
 //pages.gotoAndStop("sct" + prevNum);
//}

function handleKeyDown(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent) 
{ 
 if (keyEvent.keyCode == keyCodeToListenForDown)
 {
  keySinglePress = true;
  if (waitingForDoublePress){
   keyDoublePress = true;}
  
  waitingForDoublePress = true;
  
  setTimeout(function() {
      waitingForDoublePress = false;
   keyDoublePress = false;
   }, timeToWaitForDoublePress);
 }
 if (keyDoublePress){
  trace('You logged a double press!')}
  else if (keySinglePress) {
  trace ('You logged a single press!');
 }

 if (keyEvent.keyCode == keyCodeToListenForUp)
 {
  keySinglePress = true;
  if (waitingForDoublePress){
   keyDoublePress = true;}
  
  waitingForDoublePress = true;
  
  setTimeout(function() {
      waitingForDoublePress = false;
   keyDoublePress = false;
   }, timeToWaitForDoublePress);
 }
 if (keyDoublePress){
  trace('You logged a double press!')}
  else if (keySinglePress) {
  trace ('You logged a single press!');
 }
     if (keyEvent.keyCode == keyCodeToListenForLeft)
 {
      keySinglePress = true;
     if (waitingForDoublePress){
   keyDoublePress = true;}
  
  waitingForDoublePress = true;
  
  setTimeout(function() {
      waitingForDoublePress = false;
   keyDoublePress = false;
   }, timeToWaitForDoublePress);
 }
 if (keyDoublePress){
  trace('You logged a double press!')}
  else if (keySinglePress) {
  trace ('You logged a single press!');
 }
  if (keyEvent.keyCode == keyCodeToListenForRight)
 {
  keySinglePress = true;
  if (waitingForDoublePress){
   keyDoublePress = true;}
  
  waitingForDoublePress = true;
  
  setTimeout(function() {
      waitingForDoublePress = false;
   keyDoublePress = false;
   }, timeToWaitForDoublePress);
 }
 if (keyDoublePress){
  trace('You logged a double press!')}
  else if (keySinglePress) {
  trace ('You logged a single press!');
 }
}

 
//hide_text.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopMovie);
function ppState(event:MouseEvent){
if(pp){
stop();
hide_text.gotoAndStop(3);
//hide_text.gotoAndStop('stopText');
pp = false;
}else{
//hide_text.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMovie);
 play(); 
 hide_text.gotoAndStop(1);
 //hide_text.gotoAndStop('playText');
 pp = true;
}
}
hide_text.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ppState);
                 
function togglePlay(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   (!played)? played = true : played = false;
   (played)? myChannel=mySound.play():SoundMixer.stopAll();

   (played)? toggle_btn.gotoAndStop(2):toggle_btn.gotoAndStop(1);
    myChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,soundCompleted);
}
function soundCompleted(event:Event):void
{
 played = false;
 toggle_btn.gotoAndStop(1);
}





function nextLevel():void
{
 currentLevel++;
 trace("Next Level: " + currentLevel);
 if(currentLevel == 2)
 {
  gotoLevel2();
 }
}
function gotoLevel2():void
{
 //gotoAndStop(2);
 //frontenvironment2.gotoAndStop;
 backenvironment.gotoAndStop(2);
 backenvironment.kameHouseOpen.gotoAndStop(1);
 frontenvironment.gotoAndStop(2);
 gotoAndStop(frontenvironment2);
 //scrollx = 0;
 //scrolly = 0;
 //backenvironment.gotoAndStop
 //backenvironment.gotoAndStop
}
function keyUpHandler(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
   if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
   {
    rightPressed = false;
    mc.gotoAndStop("standingRight");
   }
   else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
   {
 leftPressed = false;
 mc.gotoAndStop("standingLeft");
   }
   else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
   {
       downPressed = false;
    mc.gotoAndStop("standingDown");
   }
   else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
   {
    upPressed = false;
    mc.gotoAndStop("standingUp");
   }
}
function keyDownHandler(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
   if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
   {
    rightPressed = true;
   }
   else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
   {
    leftPressed = true;
   }
   else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
   {
    downPressed = true;
   }
   else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
   {
    upPressed = true;
    if(kameHouseOpen && mc.hitTestObject(backenvironment.kameHouse))
    { 
       nextLevel(); 
    }
   }
}

function gameLoop(loopEvent:Event):void 
{         
    if(rightPressed && mc.currentLabel !="walkingRight" && upPressed == false && downPressed == false)
 { 
       mc.gotoAndStop("walkingRight");
    }
    if(rightPressed && mc.currentLabel =="walkingRight")
    {
    if(mc.x < 800)
    {
          mc.x += mcSpeed;
    }

    else if (backenvironment.x > -650) 
    {
    backenvironment.x -= mcSpeed; 
    frontenvironment.x -= mcSpeed;
    }
    } 
  if(keyDoublePress && mc.currentLabel =="walkingRight")
    {
    if(mc.x < 800)
    {
          mc.x += mcSpeed * 1.05;
    }

    else if (backenvironment.x > -650) 
    {
    backenvironment.x -= mcSpeed; 
    frontenvironment.x -= mcSpeed;
    }

    }
 
    if(leftPressed && mc.currentLabel !="walkingLeft" && upPressed == false && downPressed == false)
    {
       mc.gotoAndStop("walkingLeft");
    }
    if(leftPressed && mc.currentLabel =="walkingLeft")
    {
    if(mc.x > 200)
    {
          mc.x -= mcSpeed;
    }
    else if (backenvironment.x < -130)
    {
       backenvironment.x += mcSpeed;
       frontenvironment.x += mcSpeed;
    }
 }
 if(keyDoublePress && mc.currentLabel =="walkingLeft")
    {
    if(mc.x > 200) 
    {
          mc.x -= mcSpeed * 1.05;
       }
    else if (backenvironment.x < -130) 
    {
       backenvironment.x += mcSpeed;
       frontenvironment.x += mcSpeed;
    }
    }
 
    if(upPressed && mc.currentLabel != "walkingUp" && rightPressed == false && leftPressed == false)  
 {
       mc.gotoAndStop("walkingUp");
    }
    if(upPressed && mc.currentLabel == "walkingUp")
    {
    if(mc.y > 200) 
    {
          mc.y -= mcSpeed;10
       }
    else if (backenvironment.y < -10) 
    {
       backenvironment.y += mcSpeed;
       frontenvironment.y += mcSpeed;
    }
 }
 
    if(keyDoublePress && mc.currentLabel =="walkingUp")
       {
    if(mc.y > 200) 
    {
          mc.y -= mcSpeed * 1.05;10
       }
    else if (backenvironment.y < -10) 
    {
       backenvironment.y += mcSpeed;
       frontenvironment.y += mcSpeed;
    }
  
 }
    
    if(downPressed && mc.currentLabel != "walkingDown" && rightPressed == false && leftPressed == false)
    {
       mc.gotoAndStop("walkingDown");
    }
 
    if (downPressed && mc.currentLabel == "walkingDown")
    {
    if(mc.y < 485) 
    {
          mc.y += mcSpeed;
       }
    else if (backenvironment.y > -577) 
       {
     backenvironment.y -= mcSpeed;
     frontenvironment.y -= mcSpeed;
       }
    }
    if (keyDoublePress && mc.currentLabel == "walkingDown")
    {
   if(mc.y < 485)
   {
    mc.y += (mcSpeed * 1.05);
   }
   else if (backenvironment.y > -577)
   {
    backenvironment.y -= mcSpeed;
    frontenvironment.y -= mcSpeed;
   } 
 }
//add more walking functionality here if needed (ex: multi-directional).
}   


//Roshi's_Brain:
function onRoshi(e:Event):void
{
   if(mc.hitTestObject(backenvironment.Roshi))
   {
      myText.text = "Master Roshi: R- Red? Oh dear... this is bad. I've barely introduced myself. I'm Master Roshi, headmaster of the Turtle School of Martial Arts!"; 
   }
   else
   {
   myText.text = "Master Roshi: Red... You have to find Goku. My back, it's delicate!"; 

      roshiTimer ++; 

      if (roshiTimer > roshiDuration)
      {
         roshiDuration = 10 + Math.random() * 25;
         roshiTimer = 0;
  
         while (backenvironment.Roshi.currentLabel == RF[roshiFacing])
         {
            roshiFacing = Math.random() * 4;
         }

      backenvironment.Roshi.gotoAndStop(RF[roshiFacing]);
   }

    backenvironment.Roshi.x += RX[roshiFacing] * roshiSpeed;
    backenvironment.Roshi.y += RY[roshiFacing] * roshiSpeed;
}
if(kameKeyCollected == false)
{ // if we still haven't collected the key
 if(mc.hitTestObject(backenvironment.kameKey))
 { // and if the player collides with the key
  backenvironment.kameKey.visible = false; // hide the key from view
  kameKeyCollected = true; // set our Boolean to true
 }
 
}

if(kameHouseOpen == false)
{ // if the door hasn't been opened yet
 if(kameKeyCollected == true)
 { // and if the player has already collected the key
     if(mc.hitTestObject(backenvironment.kameHouse))
  { // check if the door and the player are touching
        // if all of these conditions are met...
        backenvironment.kameHouseOpen.gotoAndStop(1); // ...switch the door's image to its 2nd frame
  kameHouseOpen = true; // ...set the variable to true
        }
    }
}
}


//function nextSection(event:MouseEvent):void
//{
 //var thisLabel:String = currentLabel; //gets current frame label as string
 //var thisLabelNum:String = thisLabel.replace("sct", ""); //cuts the leading letters off of the number
 //var curNumber:Number = Number(thisLabelNum); //converts that string numbers to a real number
 //if (curNumber < 5)
    //{
  //var nextNum:Number = curNumber + 1;
  //gotoAndStop("scl" + nextNum);
 //}
//}
```

**New Error Code**

```html
You logged a single press!
Next Level: 2
ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label null not found in scene Scene 1.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
 at pokemongameexperiment/gotoLevel2()
 at pokemongameexperiment/nextLevel()
 at pokemongameexperiment/keyDownHandler()
You logged a single press!
You logged a single press!
You logged a single press!
You logged a single press!
Next Level: 3
You logged a single press! //etc.
```

***Newgrounds Link to test the game as is...**
https://www.newgrounds.com/dump/item/49a43c79e613ec32e547dc1ae8851978

Comment: In your case, if `kameHouse` switches frame to `kameHouseOpen`, the `kameHouseLocked` link starts being null, this (most likely) triggers the error.

Comment: Well, any help is certainly appreciated! Thank you for identifying a potential point of failure. :)

Comment: I will try to implement your suggestion when I find off time from my day job. Thanks again man, it's hard to find help with these sorts of things nowadays. Actionscript as a language is quickly going the way of Pig Latin these days. :\

Comment: @CodeBlue Also frame script fully supports AS3, it is not intended for things more complicated than simple timeline navigation. Frame scripting is not the only option since 2004. Frame scripting teaches a lot of wrong concepts. Frame scripting is not compatible with any IDEs intended for programming. Frame scripting is exactly opposite from any compatibility with GPU-enabled applications. So, if you aware of all above and consciously doing what you are doing, please go on. Otherwise, I advise you to learn (at least) classes, MVC pattern, and some AS3-friendly IDE, like **FlashDevelop**.

Comment: @Organis Yep, this script is only intended for a single platform no worries. I dabble in C++, C#, Java and the Android SDK. For whatever reason I gave up on Python, I was a little too lazy for it. Actionscript is a hobby of mine. Thanks for the tip! :) The Android SDK is great btw, you can expose your apps to a marketplace much quicker and usually with less hassle. :D Crap thing about it is it's a 30% cut in the Playstore, otherwise the one-time $25 isn't horrible for the Google fee. It's hard to find a perfect place, but an excellent start nonetheless.

Comment: I'm going to turn kameHouseOpen into a separate movieclip rather than one embedded within another movieclip. Then I'll move it to a frame underneath. If it works I'll have to script kameHouseClosed to turn to zero opacity when triggered so it displays properly (otherwise the door won't appear opened), but... who knows. Could be what's making it null if it's embedded within something that itself could be null. I'll report back with my results.

Comment: **Not yet solved, but... Results!** 
You logged a double press!
You logged a double press!
You logged a single press!
You logged a single press!
You logged a single press!
You logged a single press!
Next Level: 2
ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label null not found in scene Scene 1.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
 at pokemongameexperiment/gotoLevel2()
 at pokemongameexperiment/nextLevel()
 at pokemongameexperiment/keyDownHandler()
You logged a single press!
You logged a single press!
Next Level: 3

**etc...**
_Wasn't displaying the levels before!_

Comment: The levels keep going according to the output but nothing really changes otherwise (but that's likely because the same assets still remain, are misplaced or mislabeled). I will update the post with the new script revisions... **It's so close I can almost taste it you guys thank you. _I work the next following days but will continue to update this post with results as well as the accompanying code. Any help is always appreciated; and again--thanks!**_